# Using Machine Learning to Optimize Pytesseract OCR accuracy for specific use case?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

So I set up a simple OCR server using pytesseract, which works well for black text on a white page, but I'm looking to use is for a much more specific use case. I'm building an app to analyze photos of concept 2 erg screens. This is what the photo input would look like:
[image: input photo]

As of now `pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))` returns:

`ee 16 0 O e0:00,0 Seite ee Units — mrs — a es rs oe fe 1 ee “aj prt oe ISO Pot PI BIS e) WV,` which as you can see provides absolutely no use to me at all. Where would I begin my process of trying to improve this? How would I be able to use machine learning or something similar to accomplish my goal?

I'm not looking for a definitive answer just for someone to point me in the right direction regarding the best way to accomplish this. Am I even starting in the right place using tesseract?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar situations, and the solution was much simpler than what I was thinking. Try enlarging the image (About 3x or 4x I'd say, pixelation is okay), which has worked for me. And I don't expect the s/m and the column name to the left of it would be recognised readily.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a perspective transform to rectify the view. use fixed features on and around the screen and match features to estimate the transform. that should help with the appearance of characters.

then it should be beneficial to train the OCR on this dot matrix font.

it would also be a good idea to reduce the drop shadow the matrix pixels throw on the display's background. that effect is most visible in the top left corner.

while taking the picture, make sure no reflections/glare appear. the top left corner appears to have some diffuse reflections of light.